# To read database values in horizontal format with server names intact

Tags: html, sql, perl, shell, cgi

#### Present scenario

I have a database table with the entries as below which tell the status of the server whether it is being used or not based on some condition for every one hour in a day . For sample I have given only two servers and their status for two hours. :

```
ServerName  status     Time          
AAA         InUse      00:00:00   
BBB         NotInUse   00:00:00    
AAA         NotInUse   01:00:00    
BBB         InUse      01:00:00
```

#### Required Result

I am looking out for a script preferably Shell or Perl to read these database entries and display the result as below in a text file or web. So that server names come only once and only the status and time gets changed horizontally. Thanks in advance for you suggestions and help in this regard.

```
  ServerName          Time/Status                  
               00:00:00      01:00:00          
   AAA         InUse         NotInUse
   BBB         NotInUse      InUse
```

#### Work done so far

I am using Perl/CGI code as below and data is diplayed on a web page as told under Present Scenario:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Hostname ,Time_Stamp,Status FROM table WHERE Date ='$date' ");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

print $cgi->table({-border=>1});

# table headings are SQL column names

print "<tr><th>$sth->{NAME}->[0]</th><th>$sth->{NAME}->[1]</th><th>$sth->{NAME}->[2]</th><th>$sth->{NAME}->[3]</th></tr>";
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td>\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new here and i thought it's a place where ppl asking questions, not looking for free labor, but may be I'm wrong

Comment: Hi sorry, for that @Alexandr Evstigneev , i will update the question with my existing code which i tried through Perl script

Comment: @user3510848: It's not clear whether your "database" is just a text file or a relational database like MySQL. Which is it please?

Comment: @Borodin , Its a Mysql Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print this to a text file, you could do the following script.

For this example, I created a test database with your data to see how to set up the results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(qq{DBI:CSV:});
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'data'} = { 'file' => 'junk.txt',
        'col_names' => [qw/Hostname Status Time_Stamp/]};


my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
                SELECT Hostname, Status, Time_Stamp
                FROM data
                });

$sth->execute() or die "Cannot execute: ", $sth->errstr();

my %data;
my %time;

while (my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    $data{ $href->{Hostname} }{ $href->{Time_Stamp} } = $href->{Status};
    $time{ $href->{Time_Stamp} }++;
}

my @times = sort keys %time;
my $fmt = "%-10s" . "%-10s" x @times . "\n";

printf $fmt, 'Server', @times;
print "-" x (10 * (1+@times)), "\n";

for my $server (sort keys %data) {
    printf $fmt, $server, @{ $data{$server} }{@times};  
}
```

The output was:

```
Server    00:00:00  01:00:00
------------------------------
AAA       InUse     NotInUse
BBB       NotInUse  InUse
```

**Update:** To get only (for example) 8 time columns per line, you could make the following change to the code.

```
use POSIX 'ceil';
my $col = 8;
my @times = sort keys %time;
@times = map{ [splice @times, 0, $col] } 1..ceil(@times/$col);
my $date = 'WHATEVER_DATE';

for my $aref (@times) {
    my $fmt = "%-10s" . "%-10s" x @$aref . "\n";

    print $date, "\n";
    printf $fmt, 'Server', @$aref;
    print "-" x (10 * (1+@$aref)), "\n";

    for my $server (sort keys %data) {
        printf $fmt, $server, @{ $data{$server} }{@$aref};  
    }

    print "\n\n";
}
```

I'm assuming there should only be 24 time columns - `00:00:00 01:00:00 .. 23:00:00`.

Comment: That does work for relatively small number of servers and timings. But when I have Timings like 24 hrs , the hours are coming line by line in text file or web page after going till end of page.  like below:

Comment: 00:01:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:0:00  05:00:00 06:00:00 
07:00:00 08:00:00  9:00:00        10:00:00        11:00:00 12:00:00 13:00:00 14:00:00 15:00:00

Answer (score 0):

`$sth` is a statement handle, not a result. You should read the data first with

```
 $ary_ref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($statement, {Slice=>{}});
```

Then in `$ary_ref` you'll have a reference to an array of hash references. Every hash represents row of data. Just iterate over them and print the contents as you want.